# javascript not updating css attribute on modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp-classic, modal-dialog

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doPopup(file){
    var dlg=$('#popup').dialog({
      resizable: false,
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      hide: 'fade',
      position: ['center', 'center']
    });

    dlg.load(file, function(){
      dlg.dialog('open');
    });

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth, 'height':maskHeight});
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.85);

    dlg.parent().css('z-index', 9001);
    dlg.parent().css('position', 'absolute');
    //alert('I'm an alert');

    if(file.indexOf("CustomerCouponDisplay.asp" !== -1)) {
      var imgWidth = $('#couponImg').width();
      var winW = $(window).width();
      dlg.parent().css('left', (winW - imgWidth)/2);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Essentially, when this function is called, it takes in a file name of a web page and displays the contents in a modal popup.

When the code is run as is, the general expected behavior happens according to plan: the mask div takes over the screen, fades to dark, and the popup shows up.

**The problem:** Our coupon image is way too big for the popup div, so I have an if statement in there that will automatically re-center the popup on the screen.  However, this re-centering never happens, despite that code being executed.

**The fun part:** If I uncomment that alert, the image still shows up off-center.  Upon clicking OK to dismiss the alert, the screen redraws and the image is now centered as desired.

I've tried a number of things, including different ways of accessing the popup's parent, different ways of supplying the arguments to `css()`, putting the popup.parent.css line in a number of different places, hardcoding the 'left' value, opening the dialog only after everything is loaded and css updated (this one broke everything), and several other things that also did not work.

My current thought: I saw in one not-really-related post that the reason some of the CSS styles weren't being updated was because "the animation was taking too long" (or something like that).  I am certainly making the html rewrite with the dialog and mask fading, so could that somehow be related to the 'left' attribute not taking over?

My rejection of my current thought: I feel like this is NOT the case, because RIGHT BEFORE I try setting the 'left' attribute, I'm successfully setting other attributes for the same component, and they take effect without issue.  In case it WAS the fadeTo line, I even moved that at the bottom.  Same thing happened: not centered until after the alert was closed.

Thoughts?

Edit: just on the offchance this is relevant, this is being run on an ASP page.  It is **not** .NET.

Comment: Have you tried putting the rest of the code into the `.load()` callback with `dlg.dialog('open');`? When "broken" code is "fixed" by an alert it can indicate an async code issue...

Comment: I have not, and shall attempt to do so immediately. Edit: putting the code BEFORE `dlg.dialog('open');` does nothing, which I expected.  putting it AFTER that line results in the mask to fade to dark, but the popup doesn't appear at all.  Firebug reports no issues.

Comment: @nnnnnn any other thoughts?  My javascript skills are awful; I only started working with it about a month ago, so I don't know any of the idiosyncrasies it has (like asynchronous execution).

Comment: Well the `.load()` function is the async part - the callback with the `dlg.dialog('open')` won't be called until some point after the rest of the `doPopup()` function (and whatever called it) has finished executing. Is the image in question being loaded by that `.load()` call? Its width might not be known until after the whole image has downloaded, which might not be finished until after your `.load()` callback. If that's what's happening you might need to attach a `load` event handler to the image from within the `.load()` Ajax function callback.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is the alert.  It shows that the code that tries to resize is occuring before the dialog has loaded and opened.

Try putting the code for manipulating the dialog into the event handler for the opening of the dialog.

See [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open)

```
function doPopup(file){
    var dlg=$('#popup').dialog({
      resizable: false,
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      hide: 'fade',
      position: ['center', 'center'],
      open:  function () {
         var dialogParent = $(this).parent();
         var maskHeight = $(document).height();
         var maskWidth = $(window).width();
         $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth, 'height':maskHeight});
         $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.85);

        dialogParent.css('z-index', 9001);
        dialogParent.css('position', 'absolute');

        if(file.indexOf("CustomerCouponDisplay.asp" !== -1)) {
            var imgWidth = $('#couponImg').width();
           var winW = $(window).width();
          dialogParent.css('left', (winW - imgWidth)/2);
        }
      }
    });

    dlg.load(file, function(){
      dlg.dialog('open');
    });

}
```

Comment: No dice, sorry.  I get a nice fade to dark, but no popup

Comment: that's because I copied and pasted and wasn't paying attention to the fact that the variable `dlg` was undefined at that point.  Updated.

Comment: I did the same thing :/.  Unfortunately, still not working.  dialogParent.parent() I think points to the wrong component, but I tried it anyway...no dice.  fade to dark, but there's a gigantic white space at the left of my page now (and no popup).  Removing the .parent(), I get the same behavior as before: fade to dark, no popup.